# Running of program for fotobook

Tags: update-manager

I downloaded and installed program for creation of fotobook. link https://www.cewe.si/fotoprogram.html?clos=linux. I am unable to start / run it.  It has worked in the past, but after updating it it refuses to start, even after reinstallation.

Comment: Well, there are many ways a software package can fail; you will most likely need to contact those responsible for that webpage, or even the creators.

Comment: It’s hard to help you as that website isn’t in English, sorry - I can’t see if it’s compatible with Ubuntu.

Comment: I solved it myself. Looks like, again, I needed to use German EULA file instead of Slovenian one.